# Insert cluster-weight into icon without using svg

Tags: here-api

iam wondering how the default cluster theme works. In the docs it is written that it dose not use SVG, but how dose it insert the weight into the `H.map.Marker`?

I want to use the Maps-Api for Javascript version 3.1 in an really old browser (Firefox 31) with the legacy modules... but this Browser dose not support SVG-strings as a `H.map.Icon`. However the default Theme is displayed fine even in the old browser...

Has anyone an idea how the default theme achieves the insertion of the weight into the icon  without using an SVG?

Answer (score 0):

As per dev guide we have to use the latest version of Firefox. Please refer the screen which explains the browser support in HERE Maps API for JavaScript.
[image]